# UI Library Dropdown

Tags: magento2

I've created a block in `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` inside my custom theme with:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top_menu" template="Magento_Theme::html/top_menu.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

The file `top_menu.phtml` has:

```
<div class="cms_menu_dropdown" data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'>
  <span class="action toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
    <span>Title</span>
  </span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The result is a dropdown that respond to click, is it possible to bind the dropdown to hover instead of click?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your dropdown style on hover by using javascript onmouseover event. You can custom your code with your own javascript and css.

Comment: I was looking for a "clean" solution, using Magento UI library